# Structured numpy array within a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, structured-array

Imagine a `numpy` array of `N x M` dimension. In each cell, it contains a structured array with `X` elements, each containing an `x_label`.

I would like to access a specific `x_label` so it returns a `N x M` array only containing the value of the label of interest.

Is there a way to so so without having to use a `for` loop (or a `np.map()`) function and creating a new array?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[[],[]],
                [[],[]]])

# Each cell contains:
np.array([('par1', 'par2', 'par3')], dtype=[('label_1', 'U10'), ('label_2', 'U10'), ('label3', 'U10')])
```

How can I get a 2x2 `np.array` returned with the `par1` values only?
I have tried unsuccessfully:

```
arr['label_1']
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Thank you!

Comment: What dtype is your outer array?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your outer array is of `Object` dtype, otherwise there should be no problems:

```
>>> x = np.array([('par1', 'par2', 'par3')], dtype=[('label_1', 'U10'), ('label_2', 'U10'), ('label3', 'U10')])
>>> Y = np.array(4*[x]+[None])[:-1].reshape(2,2)
>>> Y
array([[array([('par1', 'par2', 'par3')],
      dtype=[('label_1', '<U10'), ('label_2', '<U10'), ('label3', '<U10')]),
        array([('par1', 'par2', 'par3')],
      dtype=[('label_1', '<U10'), ('label_2', '<U10'), ('label3', '<U10')])],
       [array([('par1', 'par2', 'par3')],
      dtype=[('label_1', '<U10'), ('label_2', '<U10'), ('label3', '<U10')]),
        array([('par1', 'par2', 'par3')],
      dtype=[('label_1', '<U10'), ('label_2', '<U10'), ('label3', '<U10')])]],
      dtype=object)
```

(Note how I have to jump through hoops to even create such a thing.)

Make your life easy by converting to a proper structured array:

```
>>> Z = np.concatenate(Y.ravel()).reshape(Y.shape)
>>> Z
array([[('par1', 'par2', 'par3'), ('par1', 'par2', 'par3')],
       [('par1', 'par2', 'par3'), ('par1', 'par2', 'par3')]],
      dtype=[('label_1', '<U10'), ('label_2', '<U10'), ('label3', '<U10')])
```

Now, you can simply index by label:

```
>>> Z['label_1']
array([['par1', 'par1'],
       ['par1', 'par1']], dtype='<U10')
```

Comment: Thank you @paul! 
I did not create the array myself, it is the way a Python package returns a function...
I will convert the array to a proper structured array :-)

Comment: Another question on this:

Imagine one of the values in the array (the parameters called 'parX') is empty. Then, the `np.concatenate()` will change the size of the initial array and the `.np.reshape()` will give the error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size ### into shape (####)`.

Any easy fix for that @paul ?

Comment: `numpy.lib.recfunctions.stack_arrays(arr.ravel().tolist(),usemask=False).reshape(arr.shape)` might work.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. It gives the same `ValueError`...

Comment: Hm, sorry, this is now getting too complex to work it out with comments. Perhaps if the field is empty you could  delete it completely (there is a function for that in `np.lib.recfunctions` and then try again. In any case I suggest you make a new question with an example that shows your problem.